# Calculating directory size without subdirectories bind-mounted from the same device

Tags: shell, disk-usage, bind-mount

I want to calculate a directory size with all its subdirectories. But I had made some of the subdirectories to mount from a mount point. (using `mount -B/--bind`)

when I use `du -hks` the returned size includes the mounted directories. Is there a way to eliminate their size from the result?

**Edit:**
The Directories I calculate size are all in the same location. There is a Main directory with shared content for all other directories (This contains all the mount points) and Directories have some individual files. The goal is to calculate the individual files size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`du -x` (at least GNU and busybox `du`) is fooled by Linux bind-mounts because files have  the same device-id, so you'd need to prune the mount-points by hand. With GNU `du`:

```
du -xhs --exclude=./bind/mount/point
```

Alternatively, you could use GNU `find` to find the files and print their disk usage, calling the `mountpoint` command to know which directories to prune (which are bind-mounts). Then use `awk` to do the sums (counting hardlinks only once like `du` does):

```
find . -xdev ! -name . -type d -exec mountpoint -q {} \; -prune -o \
       -printf '%i %b\n' |
  awk '!seen[$1]++ {s+=$2}
       END{printf "%.17g\n", s * 512}' |
  numfmt --to=iec
```

That's quite inefficient though in that it needs to  run the `mountpoint` command for each directory (note that it's also possible to bind-mount non-directory files, we're assuming it's not done to avoid running `mountpoint` on each file).

Comment: is there any other command I could use instead of du?

Comment: @AliShadloo, see edit

Answer (score 2):

man du:

```
   -x, --one-file-system
          skip directories on different file systems
```

Comment: but the mount points are directories from the same file system.